# How to to manage a group of dataframes in one list in R

Tags: r, list

I am working in R with more than ten dataframes, named `a1,a2,...,a10`. I am looking form a way to manage them into one list because I can do more things instead of working one by one data frame. My ten data frames have 20000 rows and ten columns. They are so large. I don't know if it is possible in R to make this transformation but I want to keep the originals names of each data frame in the list. For example if I have a list `a`, then first names of first element must be `a1`, etc. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: Please use @flodel solution below and do not upvote this. This is the inferior answer.

Assuming your dataframes have the same prefix say `myDataframes`, then:

```
list <- sapply(grep("^myDataframes", ls(), value = TRUE),
               function(n) eval(parse(text = n)), simplify = FALSE, USE.NAMES = TRUE)
```

I will explain it step by step:

```
# Uses grep to extract the names of the dataframes that you want to put in a list
grep("^myDataframes", ls(), value = TRUE)

# The sapply function does 2 things:
# 1. Evaluates the character vector of names and puts the relevant dataframe into a list.
# 2. Names the dataframe in the list with the name of the dataframe
```

Hope the above helps.

Comment: eval + parse is too heavy-handed for such a simple task as this.

Comment: I agree with Ramntah, a classic `fortune(106)` solution.

Comment: I must admit that this IS a bad solution after looking at @flodel answer.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I don't understand what you are after, but what's wrong with:

```
a <- list(a1, a2, ... a10)
```

?

Comment: it doesn't name the dataframes in the list.

Comment: Easy to fix that. Just do `a <- setNames(list(a1, a2, ..., a10), paste0("a", 1:10))`

Answer (score 1):

First, put all your data.frames names into a character vector. You can do:

```
df.names <- c("a1", "a2", "a3", ..., "a10")
```

or

```
df.names <- paste0("a", 1:10)
```

or find them via a regular expression, for example "*an `a` followed by one or more digits*":

```
df.names <- ls(pattern = "a\\d+")
```

The second and third suggestions are the only practical ones if you have a lot of data.frames. For that last one, names will be sorted alphabetically, i.e. `a10` will come before `a2` so if you want to sort them numerically, you can do:

```
df.names <- df.names[order(as.integer(sub("a", "", df.names)))]
```

Once you have a vector of names, use `mget` to put all those objects into a named list:

```
my.list <- mget(df.names)
```

Comment: Thanks @flodel but I got a error like this `el argumento "envir" está ausente, sin valor por omisión` What I have to put in `envir`

Comment: Both `ls` and `mget` have default `envir` values so I'm not sure why you are getting this error. The code I posted works fine under a clean session.

Comment: @Duck, I found an old version of `mget` did not have a default value for `envir`. So you can do add `envir = .GlobalEnv` or better, upgrade your version of R.

Answer (score 0):

Since they not so many after all, you can group your data frames using a named list.

`df.list <- list( a1 = a1, a2 = a2, a3= a3) # etc until 10`